# Mail server will send out going mail but will not receive

Tags: centos, postfix

I've just set up my first mail server with Postfix and Dovecot . I can send out going mail (via squirrel mail) fine but cannot recive them. Pingability tells me that `ConnectException: Connection refused` but my firewall is not blocking port 25 . I suspect it has something to do with my Postfix config file :

```
  smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
  smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination
  smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
  smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
  smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
  queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
  command_directory = /usr/sbin
  daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix      
  mail_owner = postfix
  myhostname = mail.myserver(i've blanked this out).com
  mydomain = myserver(i've blanked this out).com
  myorigin = $mydomain
  inet_interfaces = all
  mydestination = $myhostname, $mydomain,
  unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
  alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
  alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
  debug_peer_level = 2
  debugger_command =
       PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
       xxgdb $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
  sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
  newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
  mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
  setgid_group = postdrop
  html_directory = no
  manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
  sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.3.3/samples
  readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.3.3/README_FILES
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Connection refused** error means that the port is closed (no listening service). You should make sure your postfix process is running and listening on port 25.

You can use:

```
sudo netstat -lnp | grep 25
```

You should see postfix process listed in the output. Also, you can look at the mail.log file for better diagnostics if you can reach the server.

**EDIT:**

Postfix process should NOT be listening on local address 127.0.0.1 only. Otherwise, it will not be accessible from the network. To check this, look at postfix config for line like:

```
inet_interfaces = localhost
inet_interfaces = 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick reply , This returns : `tcp 0 127.0.0.1:25 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 4506/master` . What should I look for in the mail log?

Comment: That's nice. It seems that postfix is running and listening on the right port. If you are still getting "connection refused" errors, I recommend you to double-check your firewall rules.

Comment: I'm checking my CSF config now , is there anything obvious a noob like me would of missed?

Comment: Ok , I've had a good look at CSF's config and there's nothing to sujjest it's blocking port 25 ...

Comment: One option is to check for port blockage. Another option is to look at incorrect NAT rule if any.

Comment: It might be the right port but it's the wrong interface.  It's only listening on 127.0.0.1.  The config you posted says to listen on all interfaces.  Did the above command show anything else?

Comment: @Khaled how do I check for port blockage

Comment: @Ladadadada The netstat command only returned the above . How should I edit the config?

Comment: @Khaled `inet_interfaces = all` is the only one un commented

Comment: @FrankAstin: Did you change anything in the master.cf file?

Comment: Got it , just had to change inet_interfaces to $myhostname . Thanks guys :)